# How to test the code in go-lang if input read from terminal

Tags: testing, go

I have written a code in golang which read input from the terminal and then reverse that input in an array. I want to write a test for that function. So how I write a test case for this kind of problem.

> here is my code which is working

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

func main() {
    s := reverse()

    fmt.Println(s)
}
func Reverse() []string {
    var s []string
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter text the value of array: ")
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    newArray := strings.Fields(text)
    for i := len(newArray) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        s = append(s, newArray[i])
    }
    return s
}
```

here I am trying to write test function like this

```
func TestReverseToReturnReversedInputString(t *testing.T) {
   actualResult := Reverse()
}
```

What here issue is my Reverse function does not take any input. I read input from terminal so any way to provide input so test case is working